# Headless single sign on for non-browser clients

Tags: saml, identity

I want to implement single sign on for a mobile app with Magento as service provider and  Salesforce Customer Identity as Identity provider. However the whole flow should happen headless without browser involvement.

I am planing to setup a SAML between SF and Magento. SF has headless identity APIs however I couldn't find a way to create SAML assertion with that. How can I achieve it?

Expected Flow:

1. User provides username and password
2. The app authenticate the credentials with SF identity
3. The app request signle sign on request to Magento
4. Receives session token from Magento
5. Use the session token for MAgento API calls

Comment: _the whole flow should happen headless without browser involvement._ : while SAML as a protocol supports this, neither Salesforce (as IdP) nor Magento (as SP) do. Rethink your solution architecture.